# Is there any way to know if a method is running being awaited from within the method?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, async-await

I'm a university student but, since I like programming, I try to create a library of code that's been useful to me (something like a code base).

In the process of doing this, I started designing/writing an asynchronous method that's about to be used for interlocking a variable. My goal is to produce different result when this method is being awaited (runs synchronously) and when it isn't.

An example could be the following:

```cs
private int _lock;

public async Task<bool> Lock()
{
    if (method_is_not_being_awaited)
        return Interlocked.Exchange(ref _lock, 1) == 0;

    while (0 != Interlocked.Exchange(ref _lock, 1)) {}
    return true;

}
```

Is there any way to achieve such result? If yes, how?

ps: I know that I could make 2 different methods `bool lock()` and `async Task<bool> lockAsync()` but, that's not what I ask for

Comment: It sounds like you are missing a concept of how awaiting works. An await doesn't cause the method to run synchronously, it causes the rest of the calling method to be chained on the returned task. This is a fundamentally different concept.

Comment: Also, what would you expect the method to do it the task returned is assigned to a variable, and then the variable awaited?

Comment: Yes, I completely understand what you're trying to say.
What I'm "trying to do" is surely not the intended use case of an async function. It's just me trying to repurpose its functionality.

For some people, it would be confusing to have the same method being used for 2 different things, but it works fine for me. So, I decided to ask out of curiosity and interest ^_^

Comment: Note that as @user1937198 hinted it is impossible to know if result of method call is ever await-ed even if you can analize the code: `var lockTask=Lock(); if (userInput==true) await lockTaskl;`. This is close to [termination/halting problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termination_analysis) that CS courses may cover 0 consider taking one...

Comment: That's also correct but, how would this problem go with an `async void` instead of an `async Task` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to do what you want because method must return value before any operation on result (including `await`) can be performed. It is not specific to `async` methods but rather how all code behaves in C# (and pretty much any other language).

On other hand it is pretty easy to do something that very close to what you ask - synchronously return value as soon as one tries to `await` the result of the method: `await` is essentially just call to `GetAwaiter` on the result and you  can wire it up to alter state of your method.

Note that you can't really know what to do if method ever awaited anyway - so while you can act at moment when `await` is called you really can't know in advance if you should start asynchronous processing. So the best you can achieve is to do nothing in synchronous part, start asynchronous processing anyway and instantly return result when `await` is called (aborting/ignoring asynchronous part of the method).

Details on implementing class that can be used as result can be found in https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5274659/How-to-Use-the-Csharp-Await-Keyword-On-Anything and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model.

Skeleton code below shows how to implement method that does nothing unless `await` is called:

```
class MyTask
{
   public MyAwaitable GetAwaiter()
   {
     return new MyAwaitable();
   }
}

class MyAwaitable : INotifyCompletion
{
   public bool IsCompleted 
   {  
       get { return true; }
   }
   
   public int GetResult()
   {
      return 42; // this is our "result" from method.
   }
   
   public void OnCompleted (Action continuation)
   {
    // just run instantly - no need to save callback as this one is 
    // always "completed"
     continuation(); 
   }
}

MyTask F()
{
   // if your really want you can start async operation here
   // and somehow wire up MyAwaitable.IsComplete to terminate/abandon
   // asynchronous part.

  return new MyTask();
}
```

Comment: This "trick" is very interesting! Thank you very much for sharing your knowledge!